# Getting error in fetching response using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is my code where I am trying to login where I am using Async task to accomplish the task.

```
MainActivity extends Activity {

//define controls
EditText  txt_uname, txt_pwd;
TextView txt_Error;
Button btnLogin;
String response = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initalise controls
    txt_uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txt_pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    btnLogin =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    txt_Error =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtError);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String uname = txt_uname.getText().toString();
            String pwd = txt_pwd.getText().toString();

            validateUserTask task = new validateUserTask();
            task.execute(new String[]{uname, pwd});
        }
    }); //close on listener
}// close onCreate

private class validateUserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0] ));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1] ));
        String res = null;
        try {
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("https://xyz/restapi/login", postParameters);
            res=response.toString();
            res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            txt_Error.setText(e.toString());
        }
        return res;
    }//close doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("1")){
            //navigate to Main Menu
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            txt_Error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am not getting the response from the rest API but it is working fine when I had tested in Postman. Can any one let me know what I am missing and let me know if there are any tutorials for it?

Comment: share postman log to find error.

Comment: Have you tried printing result value in onPostExecute method (if successfully request executed) that what exactly it is giving or is it giving any error.

Comment: I don't understand the issue but you are updating your UI in a background thread. check `txt_Error.setText(e.toString());`. That isn't allowed there. Instead, update UI in onPostExecute

Comment: is this json responce that I am getting is in proper format {"error":"true","message":"User Listing","status_code":"200","data":[{"entity_id":"77849","email":"lakshman565@gmail.com","firstname":"Rajesh","lastname":"Rosari","cust_phone":"9891140527","cust_address":"D-101, New York"},{"entity_id":"77848","email":"lakshman@blue360media.com","firstname":"lakshman","lastname":"kumar","cust_phone":"9989219692","cust_address":"ecity"}]}